# A delta function conjecture: almost any function can be a delta kernel

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have been thinking about delta kernels, and I think I have come up with a surprising result:

> If $f\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=L$ is finite and nonzero, then $g_k(x)=\frac kLf(kx)$ is a delta kernel.

Note that by "delta kernel", I mean a sequence of integrable functions $g_k(x)$ such that for any absolutely integrable function $h\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ that is continuous at $0$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_k(x)h(x)\,dx=h(0)$.

I find this an interesting problem to think about, so I thought I'd post it here. I'll post the proof as an answer if no one else does (unless I've missed some extra hypotheses, in which case someone will point it out, I'm sure).

Comment: Do you need $f(0)\ne 0$?

Comment: You may want your integrable functions, $h(x)$ to be continuous. For instance what happens if $h(x)$ is the heavyside function?

Comment: Also, if you look at normal distributions centered at zero, you are letting the standard deviation go to zero.

Comment: @Maesumi No, it doesn't require that (just that $\int f\ne0$).

Comment: @BabyDragon You're right about continuity of $h$. I've changed the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: $\int f$ will be used throughout in place of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$.) Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is integrable on $\Bbb{R}$, with $\int f=L\ne0$. By the definition of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, we know that the one-sided limits $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_0^y f=L_+$ and $\lim_{y\to-\infty}\int_y^0 f=L_-$ exist and $\int f=L_++L_-=L$. Let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$, i.e. $F(y)=\int_0^yf(x)\,dx$.

Then $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=-K_-$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=K_+$. Taking $g_k(x)=\frac kLf(kx)$ we have

$$\int_0^yg_k(x)\,dx=\int_0^{ky}\frac 1Lf(x')\,dx'=\frac 1LF(ky).$$

By the limit, given an $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $M$ such that $|F(x)-K_+|<|L|\varepsilon$ for all $x\ge M$, and so for any $y>0$ we can choose $k=\lceil M/y\rceil$ so that $ky\ge M$ and hence

$$\left|\int_0^yg_k(x)\,dx-\frac{K_+}L\right|=\frac1{|L|}\left|F(ky)-K_+\right|<\varepsilon,$$

so the function $G_k(y)=\int_0^yg_k(x)\,dx$ is pointwise convergent to $G_\infty(y)=\frac{K_+}L$ for $y>0$. By similar considerations, $G_\infty(y)=-\frac{K_-}L$ for $y<0$ (and $G_\infty(0)=0$, for what it's worth). By this point, it should be clear that $g_k$ is a delta kernel (noting that the difference between $\frac{K_+}L$ and $-\frac{K_-}L$ is $1$).

Note in particular that nowhere did we assume that $f$ was nonnegative, nor even absolutely convergent.

Comment: I am not sure what notion of convergence you use for the integral. If it is Lebesgue, I believe the definition of a Lebesgue integrable function is that its absolute value is integrable. That means to say $\int_0^y f$ exists, you require $\int_0^y |f|$ to exist.

Comment: @Tunococ I'm just using a Riemann integral. Thus I know $f$ is bounded, and of course $\int_0^y|f|$ exists. (Actually, I don't think it would hurt to use a Lebesgue integral here.) The important part (where "convergence" comes in) is the way we let $y\to\infty$ here (and as I've stated, I'm just taking the limit of $\int_0^yf$ as $y\to\infty$). It is possible that $\int_0^y|f|$ exists but $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_0^y|f|$ does not exist or is infinite, and these are the conditionally convergent functions.

Comment: I was just curious. Anyway, I believe saying that $\lim_{y\to\infty} \int_{-y}^y f$ exists is different from saying that $\lim_{y\to\infty} \int_0^y f$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty} \int_{-y}^0 f$. You did not really need to split the integral.

Comment: Actually I don't quite follow your proof. I guess I lack some background knowledge. Why does $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{-y}^y g_kh$ exist for each $k$ (sufficiently large)?

Comment: @Tunococ You are quite right that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{-y}^yf$ exists is not the same as both one-sided limits existing. The latter property is the stronger one, because for example the function $f(x)=\mathrm{sign}(x)$ satisfies the first property (limit $0$) but not the second (which would try to split the limit into $\infty-\infty$). Functions like this are considered "pathological", because you get different answers depending on where you split the integral ($\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{-y}^yf=0$, but $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{-y}^{y+1}f=2$). (con't)

Comment: @Tunococ (con't) Thus the "safer" definition is "$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=L$ means $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_0^yf=L_+$ and $\lim_{y\to-\infty}\int_y^0f=L_-$ both exist and are finite and $L=L_++L_-$". To your second question, I am implicitly using Dimitris' definition instead of my own, which basically states that the function gets tiny in all but an arbitrarily small region about 0, while the integral remains equal to $1$. I'll see if I can show that this is equivalent to my definition with function $h$.

Comment: It actually could help if your condition on $h$ being integrable is that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |h|$ exists. I'm still not very sure though.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a theorem which resembles your result:

> Suppose $d$ is a **non-negative** function with the property:$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }d(s)\,ds=1$$Then the sequence $d_k(t):=k\cdot d(kt)$ is a Dirac sequence.

A Dirac sequence has the properties:

1. $d_k\geq0,\forall k$
2. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }d_k(s)\,ds=1,\forall k$
3. $\forall r>0$ and $\forall \varepsilon>0,$ there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\forall k>N$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-r,r]}d_k(s)\,ds<\varepsilon$

Comment: The restriction on nonnegativity is too strict, IMO, since one popular delta kernel is $\frac k\pi \operatorname{sinc}(kx)$, and that's definitely not a Dirac sequence by your definition.

Comment: Yes, non-negativity is too restrictive, but this theorem requires it. I don't know a general theorem, so I am looking forward to reading your proof ! :)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro How do you define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$? By splitting the positive and negative parts, or by taking the limit $\lim_{\ell \to \infty}\int_{-\ell}^\ell$?

Comment: @Tunococ I'll take the restrictive definition: define it as the sum of limits $\int_0^\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0$, and both parts need to be defined to say that the function is integrable. (This still allows conditionally convergent integrals like $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$, but not some more pathological examples.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I believe that means you separate it into the positive and negative parts. Then, can you just write $f = f_+ - f_i$ with $f_+ \ge 0$ and $f_i \ge 0$, and use the theorem?

Comment: @Tunococ Not necessarily, because of conditional convergence. (The functions $f_+$ and $f_-$ may be divergent.) You are correct, though, that for absolutely convergent functions, you can use your trick to generalize the result.

Comment: That is why I asked what you meant by $\int_0^\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0$. Now that you say that the convergence is conditional, it does mean $\int_0^\infty = \lim_{\ell \to \infty} \int_0^\ell$, and the given theorem does not apply.